# htaccess code causing 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm following a book tutorial (Effortless Ecommerce by Larry Ullman) to build an ecommerce site. When I add the following code to my htaccess file to rewrite URLs and also enforce SSL, it returns a 500 error when I try to load my site.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem/solution might be?

```
RewriteEngine on
# For sales:
RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php
# For the primary categories:
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z\ ] )/?$ shop.php?type=$1
# For specific products:
RewriteRule ^browse/([A-Za-z\ \-] )/([A-Za-z\ \-] )/([0-9] )$ browse.php?type=$1&category=$2&id=$3
# For HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you upload it in ASCII text mode?  Sometimes FTP programs will botch it and upload as binary virtually guaranteeing a 500 error.

Comment: @Sparky672 I'm just copying and pasting the code into the htaccess file through my webhosts control panel.

Comment: Dumb question, but do you have an SSL certificate for your site? You can't enable SSL without it, AFAIK.

Comment: Then maybe that's the whole problem.  Where are you copying it from?  If you're pulling it off a web page, then you're introducing all kinds of invisible characters.  If you're using MS Word, you're also introducing extraneous invisibles.  Try using a good text editor, check for invisible junk and copy/paste from there.  Or just type it all out long-hand into your control panel editor.

Comment: @Tieson T yes, there's a shared certificate activated for my hosting plan. But also note when I remove the SSL code from the above code (and just try to do the URL rewrites) i'm getting same problem

Comment: Hmm. I need to go double-check my regex guide, but I think this is wrong : `[A-Za-z\ ]`. Shouldn't need that backslash if you're just after all upper- and lowercase characters.

Comment: Yeah, try using this instead for that group: `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`.

Comment: @Sparky672 think that was the problem

Comment: @Michael- did you figure it out for sure?

Comment: @sparky672 yes, answers are below

Comment: @Michael, so many things were tried and discussed that I'm not following the whole timeline here.  I'm just curious if the cutting/pasting had anything to do with it.

Comment: @Sparky672  to be honest, I can't be 100% sure but I think it might have (probably did) because I tried what you suggested and then it worked.

Comment: @Michael, Then I'm going to post it as an answer below and hopefully you can make some comments, cleanups, etc...  Glad it worked.

Comment: @Sparky672 I already posted an answer below explaining and referring to your comments. I think that's enough.

Comment: @Michael- The only thing people really see or care about is the "accepted" answer.  At the very least you should have accepted your own answer if that's truly the solution... it's always more helpful to the community that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some minor syntax errors in your .htaccess. I have fixed them, pls try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# For sales:
RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php [L,NC]
# For the primary categories:
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]*)/?$ shop.php?type=$1 [L,NC]
# For specific products:
RewriteRule ^browse/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([0-9])/?$ browse.php?type=$1&category=$2&id=$3 [L,NC]
# For HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I got it to work using code I posted in answer, but I will also try yours just to see. thanks

Comment: I think its pretty close to what you also got except that I added some flags like `L`, `NC` etc to safeguard rules running over each other.

Comment: I tried your code inside brackets like this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> </IfModule> but i got 404 pages when I clicked on the sales.php links etc

Comment: That's strange since `RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php` line is same as your version.

Comment: O.k, you're right. I wasn't paying attention when i wrote my comment. The sales link works, but I'm getting 404 for other pages,

Comment: Made some correction in suspicious rewrite conditions, please try now. And give me more information to investigate like which link is not working.

Comment: o.k. it works now. thanks. In the previous code, I had a problem when I clicked a "coffee" link and also a "goodies" link

Comment: @anubhava thanks for your help. I got it to work my original way too but i was also interested to see and learn how you did it

Answer (score 0):

Is Mod_Rewrite enabled in your Apache configuration? Some providers do not activate it on shared hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was what @sparky672 suggested in the comments, namely that I was copying and pasting and maybe invisible characters snuck in

I got this to work now

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# For sales:
RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php
# For the primary categories:
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z\+]+)/?$ shop.php?type=$1
# For specific products:
RewriteRule ^browse/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ browse.php?type=$1&category=$2&id=$3
# For HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you copying & pasting it from?

If you're pulling it off a web page, then you're introducing all kinds of invisible characters. If you're using MS Word, you're also introducing extraneous invisibles.

Try using a good text editor, check for invisible junk and copy/paste from there. Or just type it all out long-hand into your control panel editor.

Personally, I use a good text editor and upload via FTP (making sure it's in ASCII text mode).